# Javascript clickables not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, clickable

for some reason my code below works in Chrome and IE, but not in Firefox.  Im using this to display clickable sections of an image, think Image map.  The pre-determined boxes show in Firefox, but when I click on them the box does not select.  In Chrome and IE, the box will fill green when selected.  Any ideas?

```
var area = [];
var highlight = [];

function addClickable(shape, coords) {
    area.push('<area class="area" href="#0" shape="' + shape + '" coords="' + coords.join(",") + '" style="outline: none;" title="" />');
    if (shape.toLowerCase() == "rect") {
        highlight.push('<rect x="' + coords[0] + '" y="' + coords[1] + '" width="' + (coords[2] - coords[0]) + '" height="' + (coords[3] - coords[1]) + '" style="fill-opacity:0.7; fill: none;" class="highlight" />');
    }
    if (shape.toLowerCase() == "poly") {
        var newCoords = coords.join(" ").replace(/(\d+)\s(\d+)\s/g, '$1, $2  ');
        highlight.push('<polygon  points="' + newCoords + '" style="opacity: 0.7; fill: none;" class="highlight" />');
    }
}

function clickEvent(id, question, color){
    var i = id.split(".")[2];
    var idd = "[id='" + id + "']";
    var label = "#question_" + question;
    var map = "#" + question + "_Map .area";
    var highlight = "#" + question + "_Highlight .highlight";

    if ( $ (idd).is(':checked') ) {
        $ (map + ":eq(" + i + ")").css("cursor", "pointer");
        $ (highlight + ":eq(" + i + ")").css("fill", color);
    }else{
        $ (map + ":eq(" + i + ")").css("cursor", "pointer");
        $ (highlight + ":eq(" + i + ")").css("fill", "none");
    }
    $ (map + ":eq(" + i + ")").prop('title', $ (idd).parent().parent().children(".cell-text").children("label").text() );
    $ (map + ":eq(" + i + ")").bind("mouseenter", { currentIndex: i }, function(event) {
        $ (highlight + ":eq(" + event.data.currentIndex + ")").css("stroke", color);
    });
    $ (map + ":eq(" + i + ")").bind("mouseleave", { currentIndex: i }, function(event) {
        $ (highlight + ":eq(" + event.data.currentIndex + ")").css("stroke", "none");
    });
    $ (map + ":eq(" + i + ")").bind("click", { currentIndex: i }, function(event) {
        visualEvent(label,idd,highlight,color,event.data.currentIndex);
    });
    $ (idd).bind("click", { currentIndex: i }, function(event) {
        visualEvent(label,idd,highlight,color,event.data.currentIndex);
    });
    $ (idd).parent().children(".fir-icon").bind("click", { currentIndex: i }, function(event) {
        visualEvent(label,idd,highlight,color,event.data.currentIndex);
    });
}

function visualEvent(label,idd,highlight,color,index){
    var target = $ ( event.target );
    if ( $ (label).hasClass("checkbox") ) {
        if ( $ (idd).is(':checked') ) {
            if (target.is("area")){
                $ (idd).attr('checked',false);
                $ (idd).parent().children(".fir-icon").removeClass("selected");
                $ (highlight + ":eq(" + index + ")").css("fill", "none");
            }else{
                $ (highlight + ":eq(" + index + ")").css("fill", color); 
            }
        } else {    
            if (target.is("area")){
                $ (idd).attr('checked','checked');
                $ (idd).parent().children(".fir-icon").addClass("selected");
                $ (highlight + ":eq(" + index + ")").css("fill", color);
            }else{
                $ (highlight + ":eq(" + index + ")").css("fill", "none");
            }
        }
    }
    if ($ (label).hasClass("radio")) {
        if (target.is("area")){
            $ (idd).attr('checked','checked');
            $ (label + " .fir-icon").removeClass("selected");
            $ (idd).parent().children(".fir-icon").addClass("selected");
        }
        $ (highlight).css("fill", "none");
        $ (highlight + ":eq(" + index + ")").css("fill", color);
    }
}

function initClickable(QLabel, QColor, QTest) {
    var areaMerge = "", highlightMerge = "";
    var imgClass = ".clickables";

    $ (imgClass).css("display", "block");
    $ (imgClass).attr("usemap", "#" + QLabel + "_Map");
    $ (imgClass).wrap('<div id="' + QLabel + '_MapBox" style="position: relative;"></div>');

    $.each(area, function() { areaMerge += this; });
    $.each(highlight, function() { highlightMerge += this; });
    $ ("#" + QLabel + "_MapBox").append('<map name="' + QLabel + '_Map" id="' + QLabel + '_Map">' + areaMerge + '</map>');
    $ ("#" + QLabel + "_MapBox").append('<svg id="' + QLabel + '_Highlight" style="width:' + $ (imgClass).width() + 'px; margin-top: -' + $ (imgClass).height() + 'px; height:' + $ (imgClass).height() + 'px; z-index: 1000; pointer-events: none; display: block;">' + highlightMerge + '</div>');

    $ ("#" + QLabel + "_Highlight .highlight").each(function(){
        $ ( this ).css("fill", "#fff");
    });

    $ ("#" + QLabel + "_Map .area").each(function(){
        $ ( this ).css("cursor", "default");
    });

    $ ("#question_" + QLabel + " input").each(function() {
        id = $ ( this ).attr('id');
        clickEvent(id,QLabel,QColor);
    });

    if (QTest.toLowerCase() == "live") { 
        $ ( "#question_" + QLabel + " .clickableCell" ).hide(); 
    }

    $ ("#question_" + QLabel + " .no-answer").bind("click", function(event) {
        if ($ (this).is(':checked') ) {
            $ ("#" + QLabel + "_Highlight .highlight").css("fill", "none");
             $ ( "#question_" + QLabel + " .clickables" ).attr("usemap","");
        }else{
            $ ( "#question_" + QLabel + " .clickables" ).attr("usemap","#"+QLabel+"_Map");
            $ ("#" + QLabel + "_Highlight .highlight").each(function(){
                $ ( this ).css("fill", "#fff");
            });
            $ ("#question_" + QLabel + " input").each(function() {
                $ ("#" + QLabel + "_Highlight .highlight:eq(" + $ ( this ).attr('id').split(".")[2] + ")").css("fill", "none");
            });
        }
    });
    $ ("#question_" + QLabel + " .no-answer").parent().children(".fir-icon").bind("click", function(event) {
        if ($ ("#question_" + QLabel + " .no-answer").is(':checked') ) {
            $ ("#" + QLabel + "_Highlight .highlight").css("fill", "none");
             $ ( "#question_" + QLabel + " .clickables" ).attr("usemap","");
        }else{
            $ ( "#question_" + QLabel + " .clickables" ).attr("usemap","#"+QLabel+"_Map");
            $ ("#" + QLabel + "_Highlight .highlight").each(function(){
                $ ( this ).css("fill", "#fff");
            });
            $ ("#question_" + QLabel + " input").each(function() {
                $ ("#" + QLabel + "_Highlight .highlight:eq(" + $ ( this ).attr('id').split(".")[2] + ")").css("fill", "none");
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Link to the actual page is here:  https://v2.decipherinc.com/survey/selfserve/1f31/170501

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I view the page in Firefox and click on something, I see "ReferenceError: event is not defined" in the console.

You refer to `event.target` in the first line of `visualEvent`, but `event` isn't in scope. Try adding it as a parameter to `visualEvent`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried adding it as parameter, but no luck (check the link again as its been updated).

Comment: You also need to add it at the call site, not just at the declaration. For example: `visualEvent(label,idd,highlight,color,event.data.currentIndex,event)`

Comment: OK did that as well with no luck.  Sorry, as you can see I am fairly new to javascript.   Thank you for your help so far though!

Comment: You changed the declaration (the `function visualEvent(...)` line) again instead of the lines where visualEvent is called. I was suggesting changing those other lines in my previous comment :)

Comment: Sorry, so I change the declaration line AND where they are called?

Comment: I got it!  Thanks so much!